# onclick functionality for dynamically added button is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have developed a mobile webpage using HTML5+JS. I added a button dynamically to webpage. But when i added onclick functionality to that button, it's not working.

My Html code is;

```
<head><script>
var myarray = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
var arr = document.getElementById('content');

for(i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
{
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.className = 'table';
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = document.createElement('td');
        var Btn = document.createElement('input');
        Btn.type = 'button';
        Btn.className = 'Btn';
        Btn.value = 'VOTE';
        Btn.id = myarray[i];
        Btn.onclick = function(){
            alert("You have Selected" + " " + this.id);
        };
td.appendChild(Btn);
tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
arr.appendChild(table);
}
</script>

<style>
.table { width:100%;height:70px;}
.Btn { margin-top:3px;border-radius:0;font-size:15px;height:30px;width:100px; color:#FFFFFF; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block; }
</style></head>
<body><section id='content'></section></body>
```

Comment: You need to add Btn to the DOM before setting its onclick handler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code is not running on dom ready

```
    window.onload = function (){
        var myarray = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
        var arr = document.getElementById('content');

        for(i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
        {
            var table = document.createElement('table');
            table.className = 'table';
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var Btn = document.createElement('input');
            Btn.type = 'button';
            Btn.className = 'Btn';
            Btn.value = 'VOTE';
            Btn.id = myarray[i];
            Btn.onclick = function(){
                alert("You have Selected" + " " + this.id);
            };
            td.appendChild(Btn);
            tr.appendChild(td);
            table.appendChild(tr);
            arr.appendChild(table);
        }
    }
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Ht0SSfDpEmxqXNfAVMV?p=preview)

Comment: hi.thanks for help. Its working fine in android devices but i am not able to click the button in ios device(IPOD 3rd generation)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the onclick that's the problem. The problem is you are trying to get the `#content` element before it is loaded/rendered.

The solution is to wrap the code in `window.onload` which ensures the code will only execute when the elements in the page are loaded and ready for use:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myarray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    var arr = document.getElementById('content');

    for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.className = 'table';
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        var Btn = document.createElement('input');
        Btn.type = 'button';
        Btn.className = 'Btn';
        Btn.value = 'VOTE';
        Btn.id = myarray[i];
        Btn.onclick = function () {
            alert("You have Selected" + " " + this.id);
        };
        td.appendChild(Btn);
        tr.appendChild(td);
        table.appendChild(tr);
        arr.appendChild(table);
    }
};
```

Comment: hi.thanks for help. Its working fine in android devices but i am not able to click the button in ios device(IPOD 3rd generation)

Comment: For iOS try the `touchend` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FTouch_events